# Is there a more efficient way to filter this array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm working with this array of objects and I try to filter and reorder it based on matching **subjects**. The array looks somewhat like this:

```
const results = [
  {id: 1, subject: 'biology', grade: 10},
  {id: 2, subject: 'biology', grade: 3},
  {id: 3, subject: 'math', grade: 4},
  {id: 4, subject: 'biology', grade: 2},
  {id: 5, subject: 'geography', grade: 1},
  {id: 6, subject: 'physics', grade: 3}
]
```

It's likely there will be added more subjects in the future. 
With an over-abundant filtering method, I can arrange them the way I want:

```
var filteredObj = {};

filteredObj['biology'] = this.results.filter(function (result) {
    return result.subject === 'biology';
});
filteredObj['math'] = this.results.filter(function (result) {
    return result.subject === 'math';
});
filteredObj['physics'] = this.results.filter(function (result) {
    return result.subject === 'physics';
});
filteredObj['geography'] = this.results.filter(function (result) {
    return result.subject === 'geography';
});
```

Is there a way more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Array is not a key-value store... `filteredArray['biology']` looks incorrect to me.

Comment: Also, just an FYI, `var filteredArray = [];` is not an array, it's actually an object if you're defining properties like `filteredArray['biology']`.

Comment: @isherwood I'll take note. Dire need got the upper hand this time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**`Array.reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the items by subject:

```js
const results = [{"id":1,"subject":"biology","grade":10},{"id":2,"subject":"biology","grade":3},{"id":3,"subject":"math","grade":4},{"id":4,"subject":"biology","grade":2},{"id":5,"subject":"geography","grade":1},{"id":6,"subject":"physics","grade":3}];

const grouped = results.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.subject] = r[o.subject] || [];
  
  r[o.subject].push(o);

  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

And it's easy to create a more generic `groupBy` function:

```js
const groupBy = (prop, arr) => arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o[prop]] = r[o[prop]] || [];
  
  r[o[prop]].push(o);

  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

const results = [{"id":1,"subject":"biology","grade":10},{"id":2,"subject":"biology","grade":3},{"id":3,"subject":"math","grade":4},{"id":4,"subject":"biology","grade":2},{"id":5,"subject":"geography","grade":1},{"id":6,"subject":"physics","grade":3}];

const grouped = groupBy('subject', results);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Why do you use `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}`?

Comment: @FrankerZ It creates an empty object without prototype, and it prevents this statement - `r[o.subject] || []` from not initializing an array because the subject's name is `toString`, for example. In this case it's probably not necessary, but it's a good precaution.

Comment: Returning a prototype-less object also means it has none of the methods one would expect on an objects. For example `grouped.hasOwnProperty('biology')` is a (potentially surprising) TypeError.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - indeed. So it depends on what is the content you are trying to group, and what you'll use the object for.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - a better option is to actually use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and avoid these problems altogether.

Comment: @OriDrori yes, it makes the solution a little wordier, but probably a cleaner result.

Answer (score 3):

Try reduce:

```js
const results = [
  {id: 1, subject: 'biology', grade: 10},
  {id: 2, subject: 'biology', grade: 3},
  {id: 3, subject: 'math', grade: 4},
  {id: 4, subject: 'biology', grade: 2},
  {id: 5, subject: 'geography', grade: 1},
  {id: 6, subject: 'physics', grade: 3}
];

const filteredArray = results.reduce((obj, item) => {
  if (typeof obj[item.subject] === 'undefined') {
    obj[item.subject] = [item];
  } else {
    obj[item.subject].push(item);
  }
  
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

With fancy es6 [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get):

```js
const results = [
  {id: 1, subject: 'biology', grade: 10},
  {id: 2, subject: 'biology', grade: 3},
  {id: 3, subject: 'math', grade: 4},
  {id: 4, subject: 'biology', grade: 2},
  {id: 5, subject: 'geography', grade: 1},
  {id: 6, subject: 'physics', grade: 3}
];

const filteredArray = results.reduce((obj, item) => {
  const val = obj.get(item.subject) || [];
  
  val.push(item);
  obj.set(item.subject, val);
  
  return obj;
}, new Map());

for (const [subj, val] of filteredArray) {
  console.log(subj, val.length);
}
// console.log(JSON.stringify([...filteredArray]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.map()` to group an array of objects based of one of its properties:

```js
const results = [{ id: 1, subject: 'biology', grade: 10 },
    { id: 2, subject: 'biology', grade: 3 },
    { id: 3, subject: 'math', grade: 4 },
    { id: 4, subject: 'biology', grade: 2 },
    { id: 5, subject: 'geography', grade: 1 },
    { id: 6, subject: 'physics', grade: 3 }
];

var filtered = {};
results.map((o, i) => {
    if (!(o.subject in filtered)) filtered[o.subject] = [];   
    filtered[o.subject].push(results[i]);
});

console.log(filtered)
```

In this case, I prefer this way instead of `.reduce()` because the concept is more neat, if a property doesn't exist we create it in a new object, if is already created in the new object, we add the element.